# truffle-contract cannot deploy in node js

Tags: truffle-contract

This is the error I get.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:631
>       throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('id', 'string', id);
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:631:11)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)

This is the Code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const fs = require('fs');

const Artifacts = require('../build/contracts/Organ.json');

const contract = contract(Artifacts);

var app;
var accounts;
var account;

const web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

if (typeof contract.currentProvider.sendAsync !== 'function') {
contract.currentProvider.sendAsync = async () =>
    await contract.currentProvider.send.apply(
        contract.currentProvider,
        arguments
    );
}

contract.deployed();
```

The issue is with the .deplyed() part, everything run properly before that.
Everything works fine in the truffle console.

Answer (score 0):

We do this to use our contract

```
const networkId = '9999';
const jsonPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'json/MyToken.json');
const MyTokenJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonPath));
const MyToken = contract(MyTokenJson);
MyToken.setNetwork(networkId);
MyToken.setProvider(provider);  
const myToken = MyToken.deployed();
```

The `networkId` is in the JSON file inside the `networks` section.